# How do i check to see if the checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement a dark mode in my website. I have a switch with a checkbox input and I want to run a javascript function when it is checked so that the colors change. Here is the html code. I don't know if the CSS code is needed for this.

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="darkmode">
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('darkmode').checked //(true or false);
document.getElementById('darkmode').onchange = function() { if (this.checked) f(); else f2(); };

Comment: `if(Element.checked){ /* element is checked */ } else{ /* not checked */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("darkmode");

checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        // Enable dark mode
    } else {
        // Disable dark mode
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function check() {
 var check=   document.getElementById("darkmode").checked;
 
 console.log(check);
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" id="darkmode" >
<span class="slider round"></span>
<button onclick='check()'>press</button>
</label>
```